# Problem while installing ubuntu with dual boot windows 7. GPT Partition error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Problem - I can't install ubuntu linux or any other Linux on asus G75VW laptop with dual boot with windows 7 on my windows system drive even it has 250 GB Raw Free space.

I have provided images to reach come kind of conclusion.

My Conclusion is that it is a GPT and MBR boot parts on same Master-boot record. So I have to remove left over GPT part form the drive.

1. In order to that i have downloaded Fixparts 0.8.8 for windows but i don't know the commands and how to use it.
2. Live mode Linux. But i don't know how to install Fixparts.

Note. In live mode linux I won't be able to use internet because i use BSNL CDMA Dongle. only thing is can be done is offline installation. but still after i dont know the commands for linux and fixparts.

Please provide me full commands list to get fix this problem if possibe screen shots

Please help me i will really appropriate it.

Note 1 - I don't have much deep knowledge of Linux and Windows Dos commands i know only basic commands for Dos.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: This also has Windows instructions where different.  http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/  Try fixparts 0:

Answer (score 0):

I have a GPT 32GB SanDisk USB with ubuntu GNOME installed. Infact, it's my everyday computer.

Try this method to get it installed.

1. Create a bootable USB drive. If you're uncertain about the process check this [post.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
2. Launch USB in Live Mode (try ubuntu without installing).
3. When it has booted verify disk type by firing up a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run `sudo parted -l`. Look for **Partition Table** which shows the disk type. Make note of that.
  [image]
  The EFI partition (also called ESP) contains some boot files. It is necessary if the firmware (BIOS) is set up to boot the HDD in EFI mode (which is default on more and more modern, > year 2011 computers). It must be located at the start of a GPT disk, and have a "boot" flag.
4. Launch **Gparted** and create a partition of size 102MB with FAT32 and a flag of boot since it's gpt partition type. Make sure this partition is created before the first 100GB. To flag partition, right click partition > manage flags > boot. There will be a remaining roughly 249.xGB+.
5. Begin the ubuntu installation process. On the installation type screen, select **Something else**. From there select the remaining space ***249.xGB+*** and make a swap partition (the size of your Memory if you plan on hibernating else 4GB would be fine due to the amount of space you have available) and a root "**/** " partition, which is the easiest partitioning scheme. However if you're looking for a more complex scheme, I would recommend [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace).
  **Note:** Be carefully when creating the partitions as to not tamper with the boot partition create prior.

This should get you through to an installation. By any chance you don't understand something or you encounter an error please make reference to [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) (same posted above), if things still dont work out, post back and I will do my best to assist.